# Pyodbc variable query

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

I'm trying to make an query with variables, but the string variables does not work. How should I format the variables **PrimaryAxis** and **SecondaryAxis** on the query? I have used reference from https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started#parameters On the page single quotes are used. I tried single and double quotes without luck.

```
import pyodbc

# Connect to database
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=C:\Temp\TestDB.accdb;'
    r'Uid=;'
    r'Pwd=;'
    )

# Make cursor
connection = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
connection.setencoding('utf-8')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create test table
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Coordinates (ID integer, X integer, Y integer)")
connection.commit()

# Create test data (Error "Missing semicolon (;)" if multiple values in one insert, thats why multiple insertions... not the main question)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Coordinates (ID, X, Y) VALUES (1,10,10);")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Coordinates (ID, X, Y) VALUES (2,20,10);")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Coordinates (ID, X, Y) VALUES (3,30,10);")
connection.commit()

# Filter parameters
Line = 10
Start = 10
End = 30

# Works
cursor.execute(r"""
                SELECT *
                FROM Coordinates
                WHERE Y = ? AND X BETWEEN ? AND ? """, Line, Start, End )

rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)

# does not work - main question
PrimaryAxis = 'X'
SecondaryAxis = 'Y'

cursor.execute(r"""
                SELECT *
                FROM Coordinates
                WHERE ? = ? AND ? BETWEEN ? AND ? """, SecondaryAxis, Line, PrimaryAxis, Start, End )

rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use database placeholders:

```
# Filter parameters
line = 10
start = 10
end = 30
primary_axis = "X"
secondary_axis = "Y"
query = """
        SELECT *
        FROM Coordinates
        WHERE ? = ? AND ? BETWEEN ? AND ?
        """
cursor.execute(query, (secondary_axis, line, primary_axis, start, end))
...
```

Comment: @Steve thanks for this I updated the solution to prevent an attack based on https://bobby-tables.com/python

Comment: Actually now that I am reading the question again this won't work because of the quotes and this is the reason for the question. I tried to delete my answer but no luck. I'll try to come up with the right solution later.